# Best way to say "information getting"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering how would I say in English "Change the way of information getting from email". I am not a native English speaker and I know this is wrong, but I the word for "getting information" is not coming to mind right now. The word deducting came but I don't think that's acceptable either.

To better explain my situation: I am making an app that reads emails from my inbox and when it finds a certain subject like "click me" it opens the email and gets the information inside it. So the body of the email looks something like this

```
Name:YeetMaster
Age:100
Work:DinosaurHunter
```

and then it splits the lines at the colon (:) and gets the info on the right.
Any ideas or really any help would be appreciated because I feel stuck right now.

*:(*

Comment: The actual act of splitting by the colon is *parsing*. Typically you'll see people saying they *parsed the data to get the information*.

Comment: "Change email info parsing", would work here?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're doing. If you're just changing the way the email is displayed to the user, then it's *change the way email is displayed*. If you're changing the way it separates the information, it's about *parsing*.

Comment: I'm actually quite clear on what you're doing: you are writing an app that will let me do all sorts of malicious things to your device simply by sending you an email with the subject "Click me". That is very convenient.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yes something like that.

Comment: @jimm101 I think _parsing_ works well here. Thank you